# I cannot change font-color in TextField component from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot change font-color in TextField Material UI component. I try to do it using createTheme() and when I add class '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input' in code sandbox font-color changes as it should, but when I apply it to the app code it doesn't work.
Will appreciate Your support.
Below is the implementation:

```
const theme = createTheme({
components: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                backgroundColor: `#EDEDED`,
                '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                    border: 'none',
                },
                '&.Mui-focused': {
                    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                        border: 'none',
                    },
                },
                '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
                    padding: '10px',
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    color: 'red',
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
```

});

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                            <InputForm
                                name={'phoneNumber'}
                                id={'phoneNumber'}
                                label={phoneNumberLabelTxt}
                                disabled={isDisabledInputs}
                            />
                        </ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works on CodeSandbox. Have you tried different approaches of [MUI customization](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-style-overrides)? Currently, you are working with [global style overrides](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides). I have created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/changetextfieldcolor-jl17g?file=/demo.js) that implements it with the approach of [overriding styles with class names](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names).

Comment: I didn't check whole yet, but I have checked already above ThemeProvider, className using makeStyles(), inline styling and styling via StyledComponents. It's strange that in codeSandbox it works but in the app it doesn't

Comment: I have investigated a bit the solution of my issue and I got the suggestion that I shall change styling of disabled status for TextField in global createTheme. I have made another ticket for it, will appreciate if You look on it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71049327/how-to-style-disabled-class-in-textfield-in-material-ui-5-using-global-createt

Answer (score -1):

Your code worked in my local repo. however if its not working for you then try below code which also worked for me.

```
'&.MuiOutlinedInput-root': { // no space between & and .
    padding: '10px',
    fontSize: '13px',
    color: 'red',
},
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there was no reaction to that :(

Comment: I have investigated a bit the solution of my issue and I got the suggestion that I shall change styling of disabled status for TextField in global createTheme. I have made another ticket for it, will appreciate if You look on it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71049327/how-to-style-disabled-class-in-textfield-in-material-ui-5-using-global-createt