# How to style 'disabled' class in TextField in Material UI 5 using global CreateTheme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to style differently TextFiled component , variant outlined once disabled={true}.
The way it was catched in material ui v.4 don't work in material ui v.5. I cannot also google the solution how to customize disabled version.
Below You can see how it was styled in material ui4 and it worked, not it does not.

```
export const MainTheme: Theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                '&$focused': {
                    borderColor: '#000',
                },
                '&$disabled': {
                    color: '#724a4a',
                },
            },
        },
    },

    MuiInputBase: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                '&$disabled': {
                    '& fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                        borderColor: 'transparent',
                        background: 'rgb(0 0 0 / 4%)',
                    },
                },
            },

            input: {
                height: 'unset',
                color: '#000000',
            },
        },
    },
  },
```

)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/globalthemeoverridecallback-material-demo-forked-fvw0h?file=/demo.js)

```
const finalTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      variants: [ // variants will help you define the props given by Mui and the styles you want to apply for it
        {
          props: { variant: 'outlined', disabled: true }, 
          style: {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            color: 'red',
            fontSize: '5rem'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})




<ThemeProvider theme={finalTheme}>
  <TextField
    disabled
    id="outlined-basic"
    label="Outlined"
    variant="outlined"
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Reference : https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides